# How to declare a child table as parent table in a sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join, parent-child

I am working on a search page and there are total 5 table I have to join.

```
Table one   (fields) = id |   title  | country  | state
Table two   (fields) = id | category 
Table three (fields) = id | tbl_1_id | tbl_2_id | value
Table Four  (fields) = id | tbl_1_id | data
Table Five  (fields) = id | tbl_1_id | tags
```

The problem is, my query cannot fetch data from `Table two`
My query is,

```
SELECT one.*, two.*, three.*, four.*, five.*

FROM one
LEFT JOIN two   ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id
LEFT JOIN three ON one.id = three.tbl_1_id
LEFT JOIN four  ON one.id = four.tbl_1_id
LEFT JOIN five  ON one.id = five.tbl_1_id

WHERE 

one.title    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
one.country  LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
one.state    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
two.category LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
three.value  LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
four.data    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
five.tags    LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER By one.id DESC";
```

I think, `Table two` don't have any field from `Table one` that is why my query not getting data from `Table two`
Am I right?

`Table one` is the parent table and all other tables are child. Right?
What I thought was, if I can make `Table two` another parent and `Table three`  it's child, maybe my query will work.

I am looking for a query, what can get all data from all table. Whether the columns are empty or not.
Hope you guys understand. If not, please let me know, Thanks.

Comment: No no no! Bind your variables to your query. This is VERY dangerous.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Comment: My guess though, is it's your `or` switches. Use parenthesis around all your or statements to group them up.

Comment: FrankerZ means for you to read http://Bobby-tables.com

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as tabular initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS Do you realize that your code means `OR (seven.fields LIKE '%$keyword%' AND type = 1 AND status = 1)`?

Comment: This is not clear. We don't know what you mean by "child table", "parent table", "worked fine except", "not working", "parent table is missing", "another parent of" or "have nothing common". ("Child" & "parent" apply to any hierarchical binary relationship.) Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Thanks guys, for your opinion. But I can see I was unable to describe my problem properly. The main reason is, I am weak in English. I am editing my question again.

Comment: Your edit has not helped. Your problem is very likely not your English. People who seem to have English as their first language write things that are unclear in the same way as this. The problem is you are choosing to use words & word phrases that could maybe act as mnemonics for things you mean but you need to use complete phrases & sentences that actually define such shorthands & actually say what you mean. Look at my comments. Where is your [mre] with good & bad code? What *exactly* is a "child table"? Etc etc. Act on my comments. Refer to specific parts of code, input & output & DB state.

Comment: Okay, actually I am looking for help regarding, how to join five different table where table one is mother and other four tables are child. but one child don't have any relation with the mother table (no matching fields). But it has a relation with its brother. Is it clear now?

Comment: Like, table one have matching fields with table three, four and five, but table two have matching fields with table three.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS Your comments are no clearer. Same problems as before. (Now you have added "mother", "matching" & "brother" to the list of unexplained words that you are using instead of clear sentences using correct technical terms correctly to say things about parts of the things in front of you like DB tables etc.)

Comment: I know , I know, I am not clear with my description. but If I have to write down everything with every details then it will be a nightmare for me. I am not good in explaining things by writing.

Comment: Btw, the problem is solved. No worries, from next time I will try to be as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. :)
This is my new query -

```
SELECT one.*, two.*, three.*, four.*, five.*

FROM one 
LEFT JOIN two
    INNER JOIN three ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id
                     ON one.id = three.tbl_1_id
    LEFT JOIN four   ON one.id = four.tbl_1_id
    LEFT JOIN five   ON one.id = five.tbl_1_id

WHERE 

one.title    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
one.country  LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
one.state    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
two.category LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
three.value  LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
four.data    LIKE '%$keyword%' OR 
five.tags    LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER By one.id DESC
```

I don't know if it's the right way to write this query, but it worked.

Comment: This parses as `one LEFT JOIN (two INNER JOIN three ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id) ON one.id = three.tbl_1_id LEFT ... LEFT ...`. I told you that your WHERE removes rows that OUTER JOINs would add beyond INNER JOINs so that is `one INNER JOIN (two INNER JOIN three ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id) ON one.id = two.id INNER ... INNER ...`. Ie `two INNER JOIN three ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id INNER JOIN one ON one.id = three.tbl_1_id INNER JOIN three ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id INNER ... INNER ...`. Also `one INNER JOIN two ON one.id = two.id INNER JOIN three ON two.id = three.tbl_2_id INNER ... INNER ...`.